# Obtaining the Dolbeault operator on the pullbak of the holomorphic tangent bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I have ran into a question while reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9112056) paper by Witten. The question is mostly mathematical, so I thought it would be better posed here instead of on Physics SE.

Let $X$ be a Kahler manifold, $\Sigma$ a Riemann surface and $\Phi:\Sigma\to X$ be a smooth map. Let $TX=T^{1,0}X\oplus T^{0,1}X$ be the complexified tangent bundle of $X$.

I am interested in understanding what the Dolbeault operator on $\Phi^{*}(T^{1,0}X)$ looks like.

My first attempt was to assume that the Dolbeault operator on $\Phi^{*}(T^{1,0}X)$ should be the pullback of the Dolbeault operator on the holomorphic tangent bundle $T^{1,0}X$, which itself should be obtained from the splitting of the Hermitian connection $\nabla$ on $X$ into its $(0,1)$-form part.

I think I mostly understand how $\nabla$ works (it is similar to the Levi-Civita connection, with which I am somewhat familiar), and from there I seem to be able to understand the splitting, $\nabla s =\partial s + \bar{\partial}s$.

My issue is that $\bar{\partial}$ seems to be zero on $T^{1,0}X$. In particular, we can locally write a section of the holomorphic tangent bundle as $s=v^{i}\partial_{z^{i}}$ with holomorphic coefficient functions, then:
$$
\nabla_{\partial_{z}^{i}}
(s)
=
\left(
\frac{\partial v^{j}}{\partial z^{i}}
+
v^{k}\Gamma^{j}_{ik}
\right)
\partial_{z^{j}}
$$
Then as far as I can tell we have:
$$
\nabla s
=
\left(
\frac{\partial v^{j}}{\partial z^{i}}
+
v^{k}\Gamma^{j}_{ik}
\right)
dz^{j}\otimes \partial_{z^{i}}
\in\Omega^{1,0}(X)\otimes T^{1,0}X
$$
i.e. $\nabla s$ is a $(1,0)$ form-valued section, and thus $\bar{\partial}s=0$. This also fits with the intuitive idea that $\bar{\partial}$ of a holomorphic vector field should vanish.

I have good reason to believe that $\bar{\partial}$ on $\Phi^{*}(T^{1,0}X)$ is not trivial, so it seems like this is the wrong way to obtain this operator.

My next guess would be to pull back $\nabla$ via $\Phi$, and then separate the result into holomorphic and anti-holomorphic parts, but I am not so sure about this.

I would appreciate any help understanding how to correctly obtain/define $\bar{\partial}$ on $\Phi^{*}(T^{1,0}X)$, as well as any verification that what I have done above is correct.

EDIT:
As far as I know the pullback of a holomorphic vector bundle by a non-holomorphic map needs not be holomorphic, so I don't even see why $\bar{\partial}$ makes sense on $\Phi^{*}(T^{1,0}X)$.

Comment: You’re wrong because $\bar\partial$ annihilates holomorphic $1$-forms (on a Riemann surface), but certainly not all $(1,0)$-forms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree with your statement, but I'm not quite sure which part of my question you're referring to.

Comment: Did you not say, "$\bar\partial$ seems to be $0$ on $T^{1,0}X$"?

Comment: Yes, but $T^{1,0}X$ is the holomorphic tangent bundle, not the bundle of $(1,0)$-forms.

Comment: Sorry. I misspoke. My comment still holds. Only holomorphic sections are annihilated, not general smooth sections.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I think I had assumed that since $T^{1,0}X$ is a holomorphic vector bundle, all its sections must be holomorphic, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

My misconception was thinking that sections of holomorphic bundles were automatically holomorphic. This is not the case. Additionally, it turns out that my second idea for how to construct $\bar{\partial}$ is the correct one. In particular, with $\bar{\partial}:=(\Phi^{*}\nabla)^{0,1}$, we have:
$$
\bar{\partial}(s)
=
d\bar{z}\otimes(\partial_{\bar{z}}v_{j}+\partial_{\bar{z}}z^{i}\Gamma^{j}_{ik}v^{k})\partial_{z^{j}}
$$
This is as expected.